# How do I wire this motor?

Tags: electrical

Help I got a motor on a 220 furnace squirrel fan and want to convert to a 110

In one bundle I got a brown wire, a white wire, a black wire. On another bundle I got a bluish turquise color,orangish light red color, and a dark red one.

The brand  has a h for a symbol with what looks like a Q in middle of it. I cannot find a model number otherwise.

Oh I just looked and I think it is a 110 lol but with all the wires still need 110 wired.

These are numbers I found after the grease K55HXDFL-2190 volt 115 AMP.5.4 CYC.60 H.P.1/4.  AND I BELIEVE this might be the model it was right after that G6698  RPM1050 /4SPEED. EMERSON ELECTRIC COMPANY

Answer (score 2):

Emerson K55HXDFL2190, only one reference to it at AquaMan Pool & Spa. Probably is an OEM part for the furnace it came out of meaning it's a custom make for that furnace manufacturer and not readily available under that number.

This motor is in the Emerson K55HX model lineup and is typically listed as a multi-speed capacitor run condenser fan motor.

Century Electric Motors carries the Century DL1026 as a direct cross reference replacement.

```
1/4 hp
1075 rpm
3 speed
115 VAC
3.5 A
4.6 max A
Model DL1026 
5MFD/370V run capacitor
Sleeve Bearing
```

Emerson Electric Company is now US Motors, no cross reference is available on their site.

This should be a multi-speed 115V motor. (Neutral and winding taps for each speed)

In a 220V HVAC device, this would have been wired to one hot leg and neutral for 120V operation.

Do you have the switch that controls the speed the fan runs at? It will be very necessary to have that item to get the winding tap sequencing correct so the motor doesn't burn up.

And also, does it have a starting capacitor with it?

If this is a bare motor without the additional parts to make it run properly, it probably will be useless. You need the speed switch and start capacitor wired properly. A wiring diagram would need to be consulted to make sure it's all been put back together properly.

I would suggest getting the make and model off the furnace it came out of and seeing if a manual with wiring diagram is available if you still have the start capacitor and speed switch.